# Why are the following two sinus integrals not equal?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The first being $-\int_{-\pi}^{0}\frac{2}{n}sin(nx)$ and the other one  $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{2}{n}sin(nx)$, so why don't I get zero, when summing them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equal and they are equal to $\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}$.

When you add things that are equal, you don't get zero unless those things are zero...

Answer (score 1):

Note that it holds $\int_a^b f(x)dx = - \int_b^a f(x) dx$ and not $\int_a^b f(x) dx = - \int_{-b}^a f(x) dx$ in General.

In your Special case you have: $\int_0^\pi sin(nx)dx= \frac{1}{n} [-cos(nx)]_0^\pi = \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}, -\int_{- \pi}^0 sin(nx)dx = \frac{-1}{n} [-cos(nx)]_{-\pi}^0 = \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}$. The equality of These two integrals is an **exception**! It holds also $cos(-nx)=cos(nx)$.

Comment: The second integral is false.

Answer (score 1):

For any integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$, recall that you have
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\:dx=-\int_b^af(x)\:dx \tag1
$$ and
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\:dx=-\int_{-a}^{-b}f(-x)\:dx \tag2
$$
Thus, using $(1)$, we have
$$
-\int_{-\pi}^{0}\sin(nx)\:dx=\int_0^{-\pi}\sin(nx)\:dx
$$ and using $(2)$ we get
$$
\int_0^{-\pi}\sin(nx)\:dx=-\int_0^{\pi}\sin(-nx)\:dx=\int_0^{\pi}\sin(nx)\:dx
$$ **Hence your initial integrals are equal**:
$$
-\frac{2}{n}\int_{-\pi}^0\sin(nx)\:dx=\frac{2}{n}\int_0^{\pi}\sin(nx)\:dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

Basically that does not make sense, I mean with what respect you are integrating?

If it is $x$, they are equal and that's why their difference will be zero.